# Bibtex warning: There is a number but no volume in ...?

Tags: bibtex

I always get this warning from using Bibtex : **There is a number but no volume in ... Empty journal in ...**

Could anyone tell me what is wrong here, how to correct this?

I am using TeXnicCenter and MikTeX package.

Comment: Check your BibTeX entries and make sure that there is a volume field in all those that contain a number field.

Comment: Bib entries of type `@article` *require* `journal` and `volume` fields (as well as `author`, `title` and `year` fields...). The `number` and `pages` fields are optional. Check if there's some information missing in the bib entry in question. If the entry doesn't have information suitable for the `volume` field, you should maybe consider using a different entry type (such as `@misc`) altogether.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

BibTeX returns that error if you reference one or more `@article` entries that have a `number` field but lack a `volume` field. For instance, if you run `pdflatex`, `bibtex` on

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybiblio.bib}
@article{Jubobs:2013,
    author  = {Jubobs},
    title   = {{How} to stay away from {TeX.SE} for a solid hour},
    journal = {International Journal of Addiction},
    year    = {2013},
    number  = {2},
    pages   = {104--111},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
See \cite{Jubobs:2013} for further details.
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybiblio}
\end{document}
```

BibTeX will return the following warning:

> Warning--there's a number but no volume in Jubobs:2013

If you run `pdflatex` twice after that, the output will be:

[image]

The cause of that error has been given by Mico in a comment above: **the `volume` field is mandatory in an `@article` BibTeX entry**. (Note that BibTeX also returns an error, albeit a different one, if one or more `@article` entries contain neither `volume` nor `number` fields.)

If you add a volume field to that BibTeX entry, for instance `volume = {11}`, and then run `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`, BibTeX will not return any error, and the output will be:

[image]

Comment: +1, particularly for the reference! I'll read it with great interest, if I find the time to stay away from TeX.sx. ;-)